# Numerical integration of the Biot-Savart law to calculate the force on each wire segment

Tags: forces, magnetic-fields

I'm trying to calculate the total force between two complex shapes of wires with steady currents I1 and I2 on each. The geometry is too complex for me to integrate by each dl from the Biot-Savart law.

So I need to "cut" wires into very short ($x$ length) segments and calculate for each and every segment and then sum up all the forces on Microsoft Excel.

I seem to understand how the equation works but my math is weak and I'm not sure about the derivation of the equation and might be doing something wrong.

Here is what I thought:
I gave the $\mathrm dl$, a real length value $x$. I will keep $x$ value as small as possible relative to the distance $r$.

[image]

I'm not sure if $\cos(\alpha_2)$ should be there or if $\cos(\alpha)$s should be replaced with $\sin(\alpha)$s or this approach is meaningless (completely unrelated with the mathematical way that the Biot-Savart law works).

Answer (score 1):

The Biot-Savart law for the magnetic field of a current $I_1$ flowing in a circuit $C_1$ can be written in full vector form as
$$
\mathbf B(\mathbf r) = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_{C_1}\frac{I_1\mathrm d\mathbf l'\times(\mathbf r-\mathbf r')}{\|\mathbf r-\mathbf r'\|^3},
$$
and the force this exerts on an infinitesimal line segment $\mathrm d \mathbf l$ carrying a current $I_2$ is $\mathrm d\mathbf F = I_2\mathrm d\mathbf l\times \mathbf B$, so the total force exerted on a loop $C_2$ carrying current $I_2$ by the first loop is given by
\begin{align}
\mathbf F_{1\to2} 
& = \int_{C_2}I_2\mathrm d\mathbf l\times \mathbf B(\mathbf r)
\\ & =  \frac{\mu_0I_1I_2}{4\pi}\int_{C_2}\int_{C_1}\frac{\mathrm d\mathbf l_2\times(\mathrm d\mathbf l_1\times(\mathbf r_2-\mathbf r_1))}{\|\mathbf r_2-\mathbf r_1\|^3}.
\end{align}
Your task is the numerical estimation of this double line integral, and you can just treat it with the standard methods for that. In particular, you should *not* need any handling of angles or trigonometric functions: instead, you should handle the cross products using cartesian coordinates, and let them do the geometry for you by themselves.

The only tricky bit is in handling the differential line elements, which are given by 
$$d\mathbf l_i = \hat{\mathbf x}\mathrm dx+\hat{\mathbf y}\mathrm dy +\hat{\mathbf z}\mathrm dz,$$
i.e. they are essentially vectors that point between one discretization point and the next. The details will depend on what integration rule you want to use, but since you're doing this in Excel (!) I'll assume you're happy with the rectangle rule. In that case, you sample $N_1$ and $N_2$ points, $\mathbf r_1^{(i)}$ and $\mathbf r_2^{(j)}$, from $C_1$ and $C_2$ resp., from which you get
$$
\mathbf F_{1\to2} 
\approx  \frac{\mu_0I_1I_2}{4\pi} \sum_{i=1}^{N_1}\sum_{j=1}^{N_2}\frac{(\mathbf r_2^{(j)}-\mathbf r_2^{(j-1)})\times((\mathbf r_1^{(i)}-\mathbf r_1^{(i-1)})\times(\mathbf r_2^{(j)}-\mathbf r_1^{(i)}))}{\|\mathbf r_2^{(j)}-\mathbf r_1^{(i)}\|^3},
$$
where obviously $\mathbf r_k^{(0)}=\mathbf r_k^{(N_k)}$. With an expression of this form, the angles and the trigonometry will take care of themselves.

Comment: @Xynon, I have one comment.  Formulate your spreadsheet in such a way that the differential length of each wire segment is a variable in your spreadsheet.  As the differential length approaches zero, your answer approaches the "true" answer, but round-off error in the computer memory gets large if that differential length gets too small.  This means that you will need to try different differential lengths, and estimate the value that your trials are converging to.